# Facebook error while login the facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook

I need to post the details on the wall, When login the facebook I got the following error,

```
- (void)dialog:(FBDialog*)dialog didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error message: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

    The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
```

First time only I got this error, Next time its shared perfectly. For sharing I am using like this,

```
[[delegate facebook] dialog:@"feed"
                  andParams:params
                andDelegate:self];
```

How can I fix this error. Why this error was occurred.

Thank you.

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024748/how-do-i-fix-nsurlerrordomain-error-999-in-iphone-3-0-os

Comment: which facebook sdk used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860401/ignoring-nsurlerrordomain-error-999-does-not-work-in-uiwebview

Comment: I am using the facebook SSO. Hackbook example.

Comment: How to find the request is completed. First time going to login the Facebook, then I call the share option. So the error was occurred. I need how can I identify the previous request is completed.